# How to set PWM fan speed manually?

Tags: fan, lm-sensors

How can I set a speed for a certain PMW-driven fan manually? I tried LM-Sensors but there it seems the speed can be only set automatically.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 2500 | sudo tee /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/fan3_min
```

hwmon[0-9] and fan[0-9] vary by system.

The BIOS might take over and stop this working, though.

Answer (score 1):

this may work ... you could try to edit your `/etc/fancontrol` file changing all the values for the specific pwm `MINSTART, MINSTOP, MINPWM` to all the same values  .. that should make it a set speed. You may have to change MAXTEMP to a very high value so it doesn't try to spin up  higher then the min values. you will probably have to restart it for the changes to take effect

Comment: Hmm. Nothing like "anytool -value 200" or anything like that? Curious

Comment: sorry .. I'm actually just making a educated guess that what I answered would work .. I haven't really played with it and use variable pwm with my system so never had to try what you are trying

Comment: if setting those settings helps .. maybe you can get someone who can write you a script that can change those settings by using one command and have it pass a variable so you could type a command like setfan 200 and it would change those values in the fancontrol to 200 and restart the service. Im not good at writing scripts so I cant help you there unfortunately